# HTA form variables pass to a batch file

Tags: forms, directory, hta

I am trying to keep the .hta file inside the same folder as an .exe that I wish to run. I understand there are at least 2 ways to start this app from a .hta file.

I would prefer it if the code can be complete inside one file, instead of send the user input variables to a batch file, but whatever works best.

1. the .hta must work out which working folder (SourceDir) it is operating in and use that as part of a command variable for the .exe
2. the user will select, from a drop down list, a few options. Whatever is selected that will be used as part of a command variable for the .exe (in addition to the above)
   2a. the user can then choose to enter a value in a text box which will add an extra variable to the .exe
3. the user will then have 2 buttons to click on to complete the form. Whatever is chosen dictates the path for the final part of the command line output.

current batch file for path 1:

```
     @echo off
     cd SourceDir
     app.exe -v --log-file testH.txt -H -L "SourceDir\123\x.dll" 
     "SourceDir\456\abc.rar"
```

current batch file for path 2:

```
    @echo off
    cd SourceDir
    app.exe -v --log-file testC.txt -C usertext -L "SourceDir\123\x.dll" 
    "SourceDir\456\abc.rar"
```

I have a basic code that doesnt quite work:

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
     Sub Hosting
       Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       Shell.run "app.exe -v --log-file testH.txt -H -L "& 
       SourceDir.Value & "123\x.dll" & SourceDir.Value & "456\abc.rar"
     End Sub
    </SCRIPT>
```

How do I get the form fields and sourcedir data to work on this exe ?
would it be easier to transfer the variarbles to a batchfile and edit accordingly?

small section part:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>  
    <HTA:APPLICATION  
         ID="objHTA_Info"  
         APPLICATIONNAME="HTA_Info"  
         SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"  
    >
    <script language="VBScript"> 
    FullName = replace(objHTA_Info.commandLine,chr(34),"")  
    arrFN=split(FullName,"\")  
    FileName = arrFN(ubound(arrFN))  
    SourceDir=replace(FullName,FileName,"")  
    Sub Window_onLoad  
        html = "<TABLE><TR><TD><b>Directory of app.exe </b></TD></TR><TR><TD>" & SourceDir & "</TD></TR></TABLE>"
        BLAH.InnerHTML = html  
    End Sub

    Sub RunProgram
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "app.exe -L " & SourceDir & "123\x.dll" & SourceDir & "456\abc.rar"
    End Sub
    </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <button onclick="RunProgram">Run app.exe</button>
    <SPAN ID=BLAH></SPAN>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The first part of the script works fine and displays the correct working directory path. Clicking the button opens the app but crashes due to the errors of the parameters.

Without the parameters it runs fine:

```
       Sub RunProgram
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "app.exe"
       End Sub
```

I need the parameters!
Any help gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all the command in a variable and use msgbox to see if the syntax is right.  I don't know if I'm wrong but I think you should have space between `"123\x.dll" & SourceDir`.

I'm not an batch file expert but where do you catch the parameter?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have abandoned the batch file path, it got it working but it was not enough for me to continue development. 
I now need help coding with option select drop down lists.
I would like it to give me a variable "value" while at the same time changing an image representative of value.